# Can someone explain what this error I get when importing Pandas means?

Tags: linux, pandas, ipad, alpine-linux

I’m a linux and Pandas newbie and just tried to install Pandas in my x86 Linux shell running in the “iSH” shell of my iPad. I downloaded the package with the shell’s Alpine Linux Package Manager. When I went to “import Pandas” into Python 3, linux gave me the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line   144, in <module>
from pandas.io.api import (
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 8, in <module>
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelFile, ExcelWriter, read_excel
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas.io.excel._base import ExcelFile, ExcelWriter, read_excel
Error relocating /usr/lib/python3.8/site-  packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.cpython-38-i386-linux-gnu.so: __fstat_time64: symbol not found
```

Could anyone explain the error to me? I’ve installed all the dependencies successfully that pandas package said it needed.

I realize it also may just not be working due to the complexity of trying to run Pandas in a Linux emulator shell on an iPad. However, other modules have worked well so I thought I would give it a try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, everyone. Although I didn’t figure out what the error meant, I did resolve the error by upgrading to the newest Alpine Linux version (3.13) which imports Pandas fine.